# Not able to split the (key,value) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to render a table in which column header and its sub headers are there as shown below

`Assignment        Bench   Demand             Past Due
Today,Month     Today   Today,Month,      30Days,Today,TMRW`

I am getting value in the form of (key,value) and I am trying to print the table as shown

How I can split the value to render it on screen?`

```
            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in tableHeader">
                {{key}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in tableHeader"  >
                {{value}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </th>
</table>
</div>`
```

Comment: It's unclear. Please elaborate more.

Comment: Could you show us the array you want to use ng-repeat on?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tableHeader variable is a list of key/value pairs like `[["k1", "v1"], ["k2","v2"], ... ]` you can iterate over the kv-pairs.

```
        <td ng-repeat="col in tableHeader">
            {{col[0]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="col in tableHeader"  >
            {{col[1]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</th>
```

`

Comment: Your list isn't key/value atm but its a listof arrays with each 2 string elements

Comment: @Guinn Correctly it's an 2-dimensional array. The outer array contains pairs of two strings. If I define the string at index 0 as a key and the string at index 1 as a value I have key value pairs. From the example given in the question I assumed such a structure. There could also be associative arrays on the second level {"key": "value"} pairs. But that would be very unusual. If user3660646 would confirm that case, I'll change my answer. But then it would be better to convert the tableHeader list into 2-dim arrays.

Comment: When talking about key/value pairs I usually assume assiciative arrays or dictionaries.. But I guess the 2-dimensional array you define is basicly the same. Thanks for clearifying